# Selecting only one column linq lambda query asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, lambda

I am quite new to entity framework and linq but basically I am using data first and my database has a table called tblNumbers and it has 2 columns, an id column and a numbers column which is populated with int values, I want to populate only the number values into my list but when I try do this I get an error saying that I cannot implicitly convert system.collections.generic.list< int> to system.collections.generic.list<projectname.Models.tblNumber>. I am not sure where to go from this, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
private DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    List<tblNumber> numbers = db.tblNumbers.Select(column => column.numbers).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `List<tblNumber>` numbers is expecting a list of `tblNumber` type and you are selecting `column.numbers` only

```
var numbers = db.tblNumbers.Select(column => column.numbers).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now.